# Asp.net jTable time field type

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-jtable

I'm going to build an `ASP.net` `webforms` and I want to consume `jTable`.

I have a `time(7)` datatype in `sqlserver`, and I have to map this relation in `jTable`.

So, does `jTable` support time data type and I how can I implement it, and how can I validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used HTML5 to solve the problem

```
QuizStartTime: {
                        title: 'StartTime',
                        width: '30%',
                        input: function (data) {
                            if (data.record) {
                                return '<input type="time" name="QuizStartTime" value="' + data.record.QuizStartTime + '"/>';
                            } else {
                                return '<input type="time" name="QuizStartTime" value="08:00">';
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

the if statement used to get the value from database in update state or put default value in add state